# Positioning header on the center

Tags: html, css, header, nav

I've got little problems with my header that has to be symetrically perfect and I'm terrible at this so could you please tell me how to make the it positioned on the center and keep the margin between links?

How should it look like:

[image]

I'd also love to know how to make that underline on hover and the simple language switcher.

My code:

```
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul style="text-transform:uppercase">
        <li><a href="#intro">Strona główna</a></li>
        <li><a href="#one">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="logo.png"></img></a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">O mnie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
    top: 0;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    margin-left:30%
}

    #nav ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

        #nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 0.5em;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }

            #nav ul li a {
                display: block;
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
                height: 3em;
                line-height: 3em;
                padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
                outline: 0;
            }
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: why no ``li`` in between around ``<a>``?

Comment: Can we get the full path to your logo? like http://example.com/logo.png

Comment: In #nav, try removing `margin-left`, adding a `text-align:center` and `width:100%`. You may also try `display:flex` to it also.

Comment: Logo is 120x140 and that's (logo.png) the full path since it's in the same folder as an index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed a lot of `margin` and `padding` from your code.

Added `position: relative;`, `text-align: center;`, `width: 100%;` to `#nav`.

Also, Added `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` to `*`

**Note:** You didn't have `img` in `li` for some reason.

**Change to this:**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
#nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    outline: 0;
}
```

For underline on hover.

**Try this:**

```
#nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #eee;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5A3nr/2/)**

Comment: Great! I really appreciate this :) Looks much better but I still got problems with making it centered because of the language switcher (I also have no idea how to make that simple language switcher :|)

Comment: Updated the demo with underline :)

Comment: Try to create a language switcher first... It will need some sort of code on the back-end to switch the languages. Cannot be done in pure HTML/CSS. Google it :)

Comment: Yay, works really nice! Thank you very much for your help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css to make link underlined when hover.

```
#nav ul li a:HOVER{
    text-decoration : underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `Nav` class like below.

```
#nav {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
left:0;
margin:0px auto;
height: 3em;
line-height: 3em;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4K8Xt/)

Answer (score 0):

You can center stuff on your webpage with the CSS property `text-align:center;`

As for the underline on hover? Just add an onhover event handler to it, then use  `document.getElementById("Makeanidforthestuffyouwantunderlined").class="Someclass";`
in your javascript.

Finally, you can go to your CSS, and do this.

```
.Someclass{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Alternatively, some elements support the "hover" pseudo element.

```
p:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```